# A Depth Like Parameter For "get_posts"

Tags: wp-query, query, get-posts

Wordpress has stumped me for the first time in a very long time. I am trying to limit the depth of a get_posts call in my template. I want to get children but limit it to a depth of only 3 as I am generating a faux menu.

Is there a way perhaps through a subquery I can limit the depth without excluding pages or checking the page_parent value 3 times?

Comment: You can't limit the depth directly via `get_posts`/`WP_Query`, a post only contains the value of its parent, so you'd have to check the parent, but you said 3, not 2 or more, so you'd have to check the whole way up the tree, and WP_Query isn't equipped for that ( and it shouldn't be )

Comment: One way around it would be to maintain some post meta labeling for the root_parent-children-grandchildren relationship. Another idea would be to maintain a record of all the ID's in that circle and feed it to the query.

Comment: ... or automatically maintain the `depth` as a post meta value for each page. Then you can use a meta query to retrieve all pages with `depth < 3`. But the bulk actions or branching might be a challenge ;-)